# How to solve ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 when use the extra C-library in IOS-Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I an new to IOS and trying to use the extra `C-library` in `X-code 6` in IOS. I have add the library into `Xcode 6` like the following picture.

[image]

The `libtest.a` is the library and the `test.h` is the header file of the `libtest.a`.

It has link the libary in the `Buuld Phases`. And it has a C sample code for how to use like the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib/test.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        test("234.235.236.237");

    printf("done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It seems just call `test` function and give the value like the `"234.235.236.237"`.

But How do I call the `test` funtion which in the `ViewControler.m`.

How to call the library function in the `ViewControler.m`. ?

**---------------------------EDIT---------------------------**

I can call the test function in the `ViewControler.m` like the following code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "test.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    test("234.235.236.237");
}
```

But it compile fail and has two error , the log is like the following:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/apk/Desktop/libTest/libtest.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/apk/Desktop/libTest/libtest.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_test", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I try to delete the `armv7` in `build setting` , and the error happened again at `armv64`.

I have no idea...How to solve it ?

Sorry about my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: Elaborate on "But I can not call the funtion".

Comment: I think you can directly call the function as you are calling in main(). Can you put the content of `test.h`

Comment: @iphonic Thanks , I can directly call the function. But it compile error...

Comment: You need to create static universal library which will be supporting every architecture.

Comment: @AdilSoomro so you mean the problem is at **library not support for architecture** not at Xocde setting?

Comment: The error basically says your `libTest.a` doesn't support armv7, or other, how did you create it, you need to create an Universal Static Library a fat library, see this https://www.google.co.in/search?q=universal+library+xcode&oq=universal+library+xcode&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.5032j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: So, I understand that you have created the library, as a test whether it will work? In that case, check architecture settings in that library - so basically it needs to compile to all targets you need in your applications (so for ios currently it'd be armv7, armv7s, arm64). My guess is that, the library was created as mac library, then it'd compile for x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import header with `#import "test.h"`

Call c functions with `functionName(param1, param2, etc.)` sytax, and objc as usually.

Comment: Is this a serious answer?